# BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in web scraping attempt

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Scraping https://www.work.ua/en/jobs/?ss=1 for all job postings I get the **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'** error.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.work.ua/en/jobs/?ss=1'

# Get the webpage
page = requests.get(url)

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Pull all text from the class
jobs = soup.find_all(class_='card card-hover card-visited wordwrap job-link js-hot-block')

# Pull text from all instances of <a> tag within the class
for job in jobs:
    job_title = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').text
    job_city = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').next_sibling.text
    job_salary = job.find(class_='salary').text
    job_url = job.find('a')['href']
    
    print('Job title: {}\nCity: {}\nSalary: {}\nURL: {}\n'.format(job_title, job_city, job_salary))
```

A web search indicates that this is likely due to a missing or incorrect tag in the HTML page, but this is beyond my skill level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand that in an expression like

```
job_title = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').text
```

the initial part can return `None`.

And there's no `.text` attribute for `None`.

Define a helper:

```
def get_text(e):
    if e is None:
        return ""
    return e.text
```

Now you can rephrase it as:

```
job_title = get_text(job.find(class_='add-top-xs'))
```

---

More generally, you want to better understand
how those pages are structured.
Maybe the `add-top-xs` class is always present
on elements of interest.
Or maybe it's optional, and your code must
learn to adapt.

Printing out
[soup.prettify()](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#pretty-printing)
can go a long way toward helping you make sense
of poorly formatted input HTML.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. And thank for the documentation link.

Answer (score 0):

**explanation:**

You are getting an AttributeError exception. You probably looking for 'text' attribute in an object however this attribute doesn't exist.

The error is in one of these sections:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

or

```
job_title = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').text
job_city = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').next_sibling.text
job_salary = job.find(class_='salary').text
```

you see it? you are asking for a .text value from a class...
Probably one of these attributes that you are looking in the HTML page doesn't have a text attribute.

your problem is in here:

```
job_salary = job.find(class_='salary').text
```

The page doesn't have salary class

**Solution:**

use try except - something like:

```
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    job_title = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').text
    job_city = job.find(class_='add-top-xs').next_sibling.text
    job_salary = job.find(class_='salary').text
except AttributeError:
    print("do_something_with_it")
```